# Defining store vs creating store in extjs

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I would like to know the pros and cons of define store VS create store in ExtJS. Which approach is better in case of many entities?

Answer (score 0):

If you define a store, the store (if globally located and not inside a viewmodel) will be globally registered automatically on the app launch process if you require it..

Instead if you create a store runtime, you need to register it before using it like a global store ([using regStore funcion](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/modern/Ext.html#method-regStore))

In my opinion there aren't really differences in final functionality, in some cases you need to create a store runtime, in others you don't need it, and you can define it..

The real difference is the order on your code files.. is obviously better to define stores globally to check them if needed during code development..

In fact, if you need to update your code after a while, you could be disappointed to search a store inside your lines of code. Instead if you have a file that defines it you can search it more fast..

Obviously, defining a store, you also provide a class, that can be utilized again and again when you need.

So, in short words, define a store if you need it in more than one position in your code, if you need to use it twice or more, and if you need order on your code folders.
Instead, create runtime a store, when you need only like a temp one, during a function execution.

Quick tip: if you need a store only inside a single view, define it in the viewmodel of the view, is the better think on using a viewmodel architecture.

Answer (score 0):

There really are not two cases, in which there is no better or worse.

The question is the means of applying to the problem that you need to solve.

100% of the cases recommend you set up your store, maybe the question you could ask is how you should instantiate your store.

90% of cases I instantiate the store globally defined in an application by the default template to be used.

The 10% case that I end up using in cases as a master / detail functionality, where I need to open multiple instances of the same functionality. If I do not instantiate the store for each instance of functionality, each change or load in the store will be replicated in the other open functionality, and this is a serious error for the user.

Set your store globally.

Here's an example of instantiating locally.

```
/**
* @class Litus.view.segundaviaBoleto.Grid
* Listagem de 2º via de boletos
*/
Ext.define('Litus.view.segundaviaBoleto.Grid',{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: '2viaBoleto-Grid',
    require: [
        'Litus.store.segundaviaBoleto.Store'
    ],
    allowPaging: false,
    multiSelect: false,
    viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true,
        enableTextSelection: true
    },
    /**
    * @method initComponent
    * Tratamento da inicialização do componente.
    * @protected
    */
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        //Locally instantiated the store at the start of the grid component, because this grid is opened several times.
        me.store = Ext.create('Litus.store.segundaviaBoleto.Store');

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            columns: [{
                text: 'Documento',
                width: 190,
                sortable: false,
                dataIndex: 'NumeroDocumento',
                align: 'center',
                style: 'text-align: center'
            }, {
                xtype: 'datecolumn',
                text: 'Vencimento',
                width: 130,
                sortable: false,
                dataIndex: 'DataVencimento',
                format: 'd/m/Y',
                align: 'center',
                style: 'text-align: center'             
            }, {
                xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                text: '(R$) Valor',
                width: 130,
                align: 'right',
                sortable: false,
                dataIndex: 'ValorAtual',
                style: 'text-align: center',
                format: '#,##0.00'
            }, {
                text: 'Empresa',
                flex: 1,
                sortable: false,
                dataIndex: 'Descricao',
                align: 'left',
                style: 'text-align: center'
            }]


        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```